# Philosophy of Science question permitted here?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Clarified my question [re vernacular - science codependency](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/67349/how-can-we-escape-vernacular-scientific-theory-codependency), shortly after it was put on hold. Also, 'Philosophy of Science' IS a topic in biology stack exchange  Please explain why my post's still on hold?

Comment: Questions about what is and is not on-topic are off-topic on Biology.SE! There is [meta.Biology.SE](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/) for that! I am voting to close.

Comment: From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_science): `Philosophy of science is a sub-field of philosophy concerned with the foundations, methods, and implications of science.` There are [150 questions tagged "philosophy of science"](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-science) on Philosophy.SE. There are only 6 open questions tagged ["philosophy of science" on Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-science) and they really are not about philosophy of science!

Comment: Note however, that I doubt Philosophy.SE will accept your question in its current form as it feels quite unclear to me (as I explained on your other post). You should probably try to add links for every concept you refer to and make sure to define the words you're using. Good luck!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question.

Comment: Did you consider posting the original question on Linguistics.SE?